# What does the $dx$ in the fundamental theorem of calculus mean?

Tags: calculus

I'd like to know what does the $dx$ mean, for example, in the following expression:
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} dx$$

Comment: Think of it as an instruction: "Integrate the function $e^{-x^2}$ with respect to the variable $x$". Without it expressions like $\int (x+t)$ would be ambiguous: integrate with respect to $x$ or to $t$?

Comment: $dx\approx\Delta x,\int\approx\sum$, so... you get a Riemann sum.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the $dx$ itself does not have a definite meaning (it can have **interpretations**, but that's not the same thing).  What has a meaning is the combination of $\int_0^{\infty}$ and $dx$.

Comment: It's there by analogy with the increment $\Delta x_k = x_k-x_{k-1}$ in the sum expression $ \sum_{k=0}^n f(x_k) \Delta x_k $ that tends to the integral as $n$ is increased.

Comment: This is duplicate of many MSE questions, [e.g.,](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1035066/dx-notation-in-analysis)

Comment: Also, this isn't actually the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus: it's a (definite) integral.

Answer (score 1):

I give it this interpretation, if it can help you to understand: $$\sum_{x = a}^b f(x)\Delta x\approx\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$$.

Concretely it's the sum of the rectangles with width $dx$ below the curve $f(x)$ on the interval $[a,b]$.